# can't select an external editor in photo 11 advanced preferences on a 1mac with OSX 9.3

Tags: photos.app

I can't select an external editor in iPhoto 11's advanced preferences, the drop down menu box just shows either iPhoto or DSCF0586. DSCF0586 is of course a photo number, and takes me to the desktop if chosen. The menu box should show "in application" not DSCF0586.

So how do I remove DSCF0586 and get "in application" back so I can choose PSE11 as my external editor?

Comment: Please rewrite your question so we can at least understand what you mean? This is very hard to read.

Comment: Adding a screenshot of the drop down would help to understand which problem you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

[**iPhoto '11: Advanced preferences**](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH2341?viewlocale=en_US)

> In the Edit Photos pop-up menu (described above), you can make photos
>   open in edit view in another application (such as Adobe Photoshop).
>
> If you choose to edit photos in another application, selecting “Use
>   RAW when using external editor” opens the RAW file—not the JPEG or
>   TIFF copy iPhoto made when it imported the photo. Important:   If you
>   select this option and then edit a RAW photo outside of iPhoto, you’ll
>   need to reimport the edited photo into your iPhoto library; with this
>   option selected, iPhoto doesn’t automatically save the edited copy in
>   your iPhoto library.
>
> Even if you don’t select this option, you can always export the
>   original RAW photo from iPhoto and open it using the editing
>   application of your choice.

[image: iphoto edit]

Selecting the IN application (in your case the DSCF0586) will open new window. Select the appropriate application. Your DSCF0586 will be overwritten.